# Is there a way to control the YouTube HTML5 Player volume manually (JavaScript/Inspect Element)?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, youtube

I am looking for a way to control the YouTube HTML5 player volume with JavaScript or by editing something in the element inspector in Firefox. Currently, I'm using Bootcamp on a Mac and it jacks up the volume a TON, so if I go above 25% on the HTML5 player, it blasts my ears out. I do have my System volume almost at 0 as well.

I am looking for a way to get the HTML5 player to go to 4% volume or 3% volume. With my mouse, I can only be precise enough to change it by 4% at a time.

I've looked everywhere I can think in the HTML5 properties, but I can't find anything that holds data for audio level.

Can someone help me out with that?

Thanks!

Comment: Googling "Youtube volume javascript" Gives you the solution https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference?hl=en

`player.setVolume(volume:Number):Void
Sets the volume. Accepts an integer between 0 and 100.`

Comment: @AlexeiDarmin I looked at that, but it doesn't seem to want to work. I'm getting the error that setVolume is not a function. Could this stuff be for the old YouTube player and not the HTML5 one?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the video player HTML element has a class name of 'video-stream html5-main-video', you would accomplish this as follows;

```
var video = document.getElementsByClassName('video-stream html5-main-video')[0]
var newVolume = video.volume

//increasing our volume
newVolume += .75

 //value of volume should be between 0 and 1
if (newVolume >= 0 && newVolume <= 1) {
    // if valid value, use it
    video.volume = newVolume;
} else {
    // otherwise substitute a 0 or 1
    video.volume = (newVolume < 0) ? 0 : 1;                        
}
```